# Media query conflicts

Tags: css, media-queries

My goal is to resolve site-content overlapping the background slider (Plugin) in WordPress. Below the media queries are conflicting between device.  If it works on Mobile devices then it creates an issue on ipads or any landscape mode.

Here is my CSS media queries.

```css
/*------ MEDIA QUERIES------ */


/* Iphone 6,7 Portrait */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .HomePageBody {
    margin-top: -970px !important;
  }
  .nivoSlider {
    top: 40px;
    /*    position:absolute; */
    min-height: 500px !important;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /*      .site-content {   
      margin-top:-320px 
        }        */
}


/* Iphone 6,7 Landscape */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .HomePageBody {
    margin-top: -110px !important;
  }
  .nivoSlider {
    top: 40px;
    /*   position:absolute; */
    min-height: 500px !important;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .site-content {
    margin-top: -320px !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since min/max-device-width has deprecated, you can use the [orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) queries for portrait and landscape.
So your code will be like that:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
...
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
...
}
```

Comment: Orientation is already there in my code however, it is still conflicting between devices.  I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: i must admit that i don't use wordpress nor knowing it's plugins. If you try to use this code above and it didn't change i guess the plugin override the css with js even with the !important. if you can access the plugin js you can modify or override it with js. another solution is to do it without it and write your own code?